# How does the container use more memory than the limit?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

My project might be an overcommitted system, and I have to improve the reliability by specifying an appropriate container mem limit, by which the total mem of the node should not be divided. But I'm confused with the following statements in the Kubernetes v1.1 doc [Resource of Qos](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/proposals/resource-qos.html):

> ### Incompressible Resource Guarantees
>
> - if they exceed their memory request, they could be killed (if some other container needs memory)
> - Containers will be killed if they use more memory than their limit.

and the command `docker stats` shows a "LIMIT" for each container:

[image]

I think it means that containers will not use mems more than the "LIMIT" since I've met sometimes the `MEM%` stays at `100%` for a while, so how and when the containers are killed?

### Update

I think OOM Killer is enabled with the default value `0`.

```
> cat /proc/sys/vm/oom_kill_allocating_task
0
```

Answer (score 1):

Cgroup memory limit feature is used, so I recommend to read cgroup doc:

> Tasks that attempt to consume more memory than they are allowed are
>   immediately killed by the OOM killer.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-memory.html

Comment: Thanks! Actually, my containers are used to computation, the max mem will be `16G`, so the container will use more the `8.59G` limit. So how to explain the `100% LIMIT` in the `docker stats`? It stays for a while and not any containers are killed.

Comment: Is OOM killer enabled?

Comment: Isn't it enabled by default? I think it might be not the problem, but the fact that containers will **not** consume more memory than they are allowed, according to the "LIMIT" column.

Comment: the OOM killer is enabled, please check the `Update` in the question.